# How to know when the project started in JIRA?

Tags: jira, reporting, timeline

I am an admin for JIRA project following SCRUM approach. I am trying to report to my direct manager when the project was started.

I went to `Settings`and `Timesheets`.. and many places. And I cannot find this information .

Any idea where to find when the JIRA project is started exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the first issue created (`<PROJECT>-1`) would give you a fairly acceptable ballpark date, unless by 'project' you mean something else that's not the actual Jira project.

Either way, take into account that this information, out of context, might be just [data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIKW_pyramid), not an actual information.